# Return repeated count of given string position

Tags: python, repeat

I need the program to return the amount of times the letter of the index I have given it has been repeated in python. For instance, If I give it:

```
numLen("This is a Test", 3)
```

I want it to return

```
3
```

because s is said three times.
Right now I only have :

```
def numLen(string, num):
    for s in string:
        print(s + ' ' + str(test.count(s)))
```

Nothing I know, but I'm at a loss guys.

Comment: Your function parameters don't match; where is `test` defined?

Comment: `string.count(string[num])` should work.

Comment: You still have `test.count(s)` in your code attempt to fix. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to get the character at the given index, then return the count:

```
def numLen(inputstring, index):
    char = inputstring[index]
    return inputstring.count(char)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def numLen(inputstring, index):
...     char = inputstring[index]
...     return inputstring.count(char)
... 
>>> numLen("This is a Test", 3)
3
```

Python indexes start at *zero*, so position 3 is the letter `s` in your input example.

Comment: I was under the impression that using `string` as a variable name was bad practice since it is a well-known module in the standard library.

Comment: @Volatility: Perhaps; updated to be a little more explicit in the name choice.

Comment: You should still take care. There's actually a string module that can be imported as: import string

Comment: @5T41N5: Yes, that is what Volatility and I were discussing.

Answer (score 0):

`def count_occurences(line, index): return line.count(line[index])`